The Rust Programming Language 17章 リスト17-15 のコードを解説いただきたい
The Rust Programming Language を読みながら、Rustを勉強しています。
17章 のステートオブジェクトを読んでいたのですが、リスト17-15でつまづきました。
Box<Self> については、型がBox内に保持されているからと理解できました。
しかしながら、要約ですが「takeメソッドを使ってself.stateにNoneを一時的に残すことで、Postが古いstate値を使えないことが保証される」辺りが理解できません。
普通の可変変数に代入するときに古い値を使えるかなどとは考えないのでは？と思いました。
また、トレイトオブジェクトをOptionで保持する理由がこのあたりに関係しているかと思うのですが、最初からOptionを使わなければこの問題も避けられるのでは？と思いました。
不勉強で申し訳ないのですが、分かりやすく解説いただけないでしょうか。

impl Post {
    // --snip--
    pub fn request_review(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.request_review())
        }
    }
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<State>;
}

struct Draft {}

impl State for Draft {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<State> {
        Box::new(PendingReview {})
    }
}

struct PendingReview {}

impl State for PendingReview {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<State> {
        self
    }
}




最初から Option を使わなければこの問題も避けられるのでは？と思いました。

その形でやってみれば問題を避けられないことをコンパイラが教えてくれるはずです。
The Rust Programming Language で前提とする状況がややこしいのですごく単純化したコードにするとこんな感じだと思いますが……
struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn create_new_foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<Self> {
        Box::new(Foo {})
    }
}

struct Bar {
    state: Option<Box<Foo>>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Bar {
        Bar {
            state: Some(Box::new(Foo {})),
        }
    }
    fn update(&mut self) {
        if let Some(s) = self.state.take() {
            self.state = Some(s.create_new_foo());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar::new();
    Bar::update(&mut bar);
}

ここから Option を取り除けばよいのではという質問者の考えを形にするとおそらく以下のようなものでしょう。
struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn create_new_foo(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<Self> {
        Box::new(Foo {})
    }
}

struct Bar {
    state: Box<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Bar {
        Bar {
            state: Box::new(Foo {}),
        }
    }
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.state = self.state.create_new_foo();  // ここでエラー
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar::new();
    Bar::update(&mut bar);
}

エラーが出るのでエラーの内容をよく見てください。 端的に言えば借用規則に反します。
Bar::update は参照を受けっている (借用している) に過ぎないのでその所有権を勝手に手放すことが出来ないのです。

確かに可変借用したものの所有権は移動できないですね。しかし、パターンマッチングの時点では所有権の移動が発生するのではないかと思いました。調べてみると、次の記事でもOption周りについては質問されているようでした。Optionに対してtake()を呼ぶのはなぜか

take()メソッドを調べた結果、おそらく自己解決しました。
前提条件

トレイトで定義されたrequest_review は、古い状態の上書きのためself.stateの所有権を奪う必要がある。
self.state は可変借用のため、本来は所有権を奪うことはできない。

take()メソッドについて

unsafeなRustを呼び出しメモリを操作することで、本来不可能である可変参照した値の所有権を移動することが可能。
Option::take()で定義されているため、ステートオブジェクトをOptionでくるむ必要がある。

「古いstate値を使えないことを保証する」関連について
take()メソッドを使用した移動元には自動的にNoneを残すことになるから
（所有権が移動してもあくまで可変借用であるため、純粋にムーブすることはできないからか）
自分の中では以上のようにまとめることができました。
ミスや誤解等あればコメントいただけると幸いです。
